# Controlling a motor with potentiometer

Tags: arduino

I am trying to use my arduino and a potentiometer to make a motor spin one way when the potentiometer is past 0 and spin the other when the potentiometer is past 0 the other direction. The code is working on the SensorValue < 512 side but not on the >507 side.

```
const int analogInPin = A1;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int analogOutPin = 9; // 
const int analogOutPin_2 = 11; //
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot
int outputValue = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)


void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600); 

}

void loop() {

  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);            

  if (sensorValue < 507) {     

    analogWrite(analogOutPin, LOW);  
    outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 512, 0, 255);  

  analogWrite(analogOutPin_2, outputValue);    
  } 
   if (512 > sensorValue) {     

    analogWrite(analogOutPin_2, LOW);  
    outputValue = map(sensorValue, 512, 1023, 0, 255);  

 analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue);    
  } 
  else {


 }

  delay(2);                     

}
```

Comment: Other than figuring out what the correct map values are I think this is right maybe my chip is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving issues such as this. I recommend a few strategic prints and a for loop to simulate the data range, reveals the following code with a few tweaks works better

```
const int analogInPin = A1;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int analogOutPin = 9; // 
const int analogOutPin_2 = 11; //
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot
int outputValue = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Begin1");  
}

void loop() {
//  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);            
  for (sensorValue = 0; sensorValue < 1024; sensorValue++) {
    Serial.print("sensorValue = ");
    Serial.print(sensorValue);

    if (sensorValue < 507) {     
      outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 512, 255, 0);  
      Serial.print(" Forward : ");  
      Serial.print(outputValue);  
      analogWrite(analogOutPin, LOW);  
      analogWrite(analogOutPin_2, outputValue);    
    } else if (512 < sensorValue) {     
      outputValue = map(sensorValue, 512, 1023, 0, 255);  
      Serial.print(" Reverse : ");  
      Serial.print(outputValue);  
      analogWrite(analogOutPin_2, LOW);  
      analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue);    
    } 
    Serial.println();

  }
  while(1);
  delay(1000);                     
}
```